# slider de varios items

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo este código

```css
  .categoria-slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-left: 8%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.categoria-slider .item {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  width: 255px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.categoria-slider h1 {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.description {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12%;
  top: -12%;
  background: #29252c;
  text-align: center;
}

.description a {
  color: #fff;
```

```html
<div class="categoria-slider">
  <h1>Categorías</h1>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/categoria.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <a href="#">Categoria</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/categoria.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <a href="#">Categoria</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/categoria.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <a href="#">Categoria</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/categoria.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <a href="#">Categoria</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/categoria.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <a href="#">Categoria</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Estoy intentando hacer un slider de tal manera que si pongo unas flechas a los lados usando jquery al evento de click para darle una animacion con el atributo de css

```
position:relative;
left: -255px;
```

pero al usar el inspector veo q el cuarto item esta debajo solo que no se ve, pero desearia que aparezca por el lado derecho y dar esa sensacion de slide

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un DIV que englobe a todos los sliders.

Lo que te pasa ahora es que:

**.categoria-slider .item** = 255px

Por tanto, cuando la pantalla mide vamos a poner 900px, caben 3 en linea y el cuarto ya no, y se va a la siguiente fila, por eso lo ves abajo.

Esto se soluciona muy facil, pon un div entre:

**.categoria-slider** y **.categoria-slider .item** que tenga el ancho por ejemplo de los 4 div que contienen (255*4) de fotma que:

**.categoria-slider .box**{
 float: left:
 width: 1020px
 height: 200px;
}

Recuerda que ahora lo que tienes que mover es este nuevo bloque, no los items de dentro ok?

EDITO: Acabo de ver que tu DIV principal tiene un witdh de 100%, si va a trabajar con %, los items tienen que tener un 25% de witdh, y el recorrido en cada click tiene que ser -100%. (esto es un poco complicado de entender las primeras veces asi que te recomiendo si estas empezando que al DIV principal le quites el 100% y le pongas un tamaño en PX para hacer funcionar bien el ejemplo y luego ya indagas con % que además, te valdra para moviles y demas temas responsives.

Comment: amigo gracias, funciono perfectamente, lo que hice ademas de lo que me dijiste fue crear otro div mas encima para que sirva como marco, es decir seria como una ventana para el div que contiene los item, pero me doy cuenta que q el ancho de ese contenedor de items es fijo, me gustaria que ese ancho sea dinamico deacuerdo a la cantidad de items q tengo, es decir que no importa la cantidad de items que tenga ese contenedor, este siempre debe mostrarse en una linea, lo que implica que el ancho del contenedor aumente conforme aya mas items... gracias por tu apoyo